# QT - Exibir WebCam em uma QLabel usando outra Thread?

Tags: c++, thread, qt, opencv

Olá, estou fazendo um projeto em C++ usando GUI QT. No projeto em questão preciso exibir imagens de uma camera na janela, porém ao fazer isso, o desempenho da janela fica muito comprometido, todos os outros botoes e funcionalidades que inclui na janela ficam lerdos, sobrecarregados ao que parece. Eis abaixo o código da captura das imagems do dispositivo.

```
  void mainwindow::on_ButtonShowCamera_clicked(){

ligaCam = true;

if(!this->cap.isOpened()){ // se ja estiver aberto, nao abre denovo //
    this->cap.open(0);
}

QImage img;

while(ligaCam == true){
    Mat frame;
    this->cap.read(frame);

    img = MatToQImage(frame); // converte tipo Mat para QImage //
    ui->labelScreen->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
    ui->labelScreen->setScaledContents(true);

    qApp->processEvents(); 
   //imshow("help", frame);

    if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
        break;
}
```

}

A variável ligaCam se encarrega de trocar o valor quando clico em outro botao (Fechar Camera) para sair do laço.

A minha Duvida é se existiria alguma maneira de exibir as imagens da camera no QLabel utilizando outra thread? Ou se existiria alguma forma de exibir as imagens sem sobrecarregar a janela em questão?  Desde já, agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A interface gráfica parece travada porque você está consumindo todo o recurso de sua thread (a principal) ao fazer um laço praticamente "infinito".

Você pode tentar mover o código de atualização para outra thread, mas é mais simples usar um temporizador para fazer capturas periódicas da imagem da Webcam:

1. Na classe da janela em que você exibe a imagem da câmera (por exemplo, pode ser em outra classe dependendo da sua organização), instancie um [`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html). Defina para ele um intervalo de atualização desejado (por exemplo, a cada 100 milisegundos), e inicie. **Não se esqueça de conectar ao slot [`timeout()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#timeout).**
2. Na chamada do método conectado ao slot `timeout()` (que vai executar a cada período de intervalo configurado), leia a imagem da Webcam e atualize o `QLabel` da mesma forma como você está fazendo.

Exemplo de código:

```
[...]

<Classe>::<Classe>() { // Construtor (por exemplo)
    QTimer *pTimer = new QTimer(this);
    QObject::connect(pTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onTimeout()));
    pTimer->start(100);
}

[...]

<Classe>::onTimeout() {
    Mat frame;
    this->cap.read(frame);

    img = MatToQImage(frame); // converte tipo Mat para QImage //
    ui->labelScreen->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
    ui->labelScreen->setScaledContents(true);
}
```

Um exemplo mais completo que utiliza essa abordagem pode ser encontrado [neste meu projeto de teste](https://github.com/luigivieira/CamTest).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, segui o seu conselho acima mas agora me deparei com a seguinte mensagem de erro:  'SIGNAL was not declared in this scope'.  E a segunda mensagem é 'macro signal passed 3 arguments but takes just 1' .  Até instanciei as bibliotecas do QTimer, embora nao precisasse, mas o erro persiste. Saberia oq poderia ser este problema?

Comment: Provavelmente alguma coisa errada com a declaração do seu método `onTimeout` (ele foi declarado como um *slot*, em uma classe que herda de `QObject` e que usa a macro `Q_OBJECT` - tal qual indica [a documentação do Qt para o mecanismo de comunicação entre objetos?](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/signalsandslots.html)). De todas as formas, como é outro problema você deveria abrir outra pergunta. :)

Comment: Ah, e se essa resposta te ajudou, por favor [considere marcá-la como aceita](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Consegui! na verdade estava tudo certo com a macro e a classe, o erro estava na declaração do connect(), Acho q perdi alguns parenteses da função, e o meu compilador nao acusou rs, Bom, Obrigado pela resposta, resolveu meu problema amigo, Abraço!

Comment: Resposta aceita, obrigado novamente.